# A Better Way to Create a Table with Columns That Are Functions of the Previous Column?

Tags: r, dplyr

Using R, I want to create a table of 10,000 scenarios (rows) and perhaps 50 columns that represent annual portfolio balances. Each column's value should equal the previous column's value minus a constant amount of spending (say, $40,000 a year) and then multiplied by a randomly-generated market return (expressed as a growth rate). All scenario balances begin at $1,000,000 at year zero.

For example, the  market returns 6% in year 1 (growth rate 1.06). The investor has $1M, spends $40,000, leaving $960,000 and then earns 6% on that, leaving a year one balance of $1,017,600. The following column(year) starts with $1,017,600, spends $40,000, then applies a new random market return to created the year two balance. I repeat this for 50 columns (years) and repeat that process for 10,000 50-year scenarios.

I do that with loops as follows:

```
# Set initial values

set.seed(27514)
n <- 10000 # number of scenarios
mu <- .05 # market return expectation
sigma <- .12 # market return volatility
portfolio <- 1000000 # $1,000000
yrs <- 50 # years of market returns and corresponding portfolio balances
spend <- 40000 # dollar amount to spend annually
balances <- matrix(nrow=n,ncol=yrs)


# function newbalance returns a portfolio balance for the current year (column) by subtracting an amount spent from the portfolio's
# previous balance (column - 1) and then applying the current year's market return to the remaining balance. If the
# new balance is negative, it is changed to zero.

newBalance <- function (lastYearBal,currentReturn,spend) { max(0,(lastYearBal - spend) * currentReturn) }

# Create table of n rows and (yrs = 50) columns of random market returns, expressed as growth rates (1.0 plus return)

marketReturns <- matrix(rlnorm(n*yrs,mu,sigma), n, yrs) 

# Create 50 columns of n rows of portfolio balances based on the market returns matrix and constant annual spending = spend

for (i in 1:n) {
  for (j in 1:yrs) {
    if (j == 1) {oldBalance <- portfolio} 
    else {oldBalance <- balances[i,j-1]}
    balances[i,j] <- newBalance(oldBalance,marketReturns[i,j],spend)
  }
}
```

I am looking for a "better" way to do this and by better I mean 1) more clear for someone to understand the code, 2) faster and, hopefully, 3) both.

I just began using dplyr and wonder if there is a way to do this with Mutate, perhaps.

Suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The OP's loop is okay apart from not vectorizing `max`. I would write it as

```
do.call(cbind,
Reduce( 
  function(x,y) pmax(0, (x - spend)*y), 
  as.data.frame(marketReturns), 
  init = portfolio, 
  accumulate = TRUE
)[-1]
)
```

which gives

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
 [1,] 1225023.5 1356133.0 1411918.2 1422467.3 1333403.1
 [2,]  886324.3 1116834.2 1393490.6 1290055.2 1188176.0
 [3,] 1263106.3 1211609.4 1187170.0 1256445.9 1129850.1
 [4,]  751897.5  749431.7  637428.4  717144.9  795654.3
 [5,]  972910.2  832125.1  852293.3  717697.8  664908.3
 [6,]  994046.2  922805.8  880951.7  814622.0  674656.3
 [7,] 1077494.7  970762.1 1097041.3  963056.8  834362.0
 [8,] 1034696.9 1145020.8 1132916.7 1292145.0 1567837.9
 [9,] 1042336.3 1107492.6 1204792.5 1196458.1  991649.2
[10,]  860172.0  830692.4  934326.0  945027.2  932220.1
```

`Reduce` is a pretty standard tool for the question in the title:

> A Better Way to Create a Table with Columns That Are Functions of the Previous Column?

`Reduce` iterates over lists; so `as.data.frame` is used above to convert `marketReturns` into a list of columns (aka, a data.frame). `pmax(...)` takes the "parallel maximum" of items from multiple vectors of the same length. Scalars like `0` and `portfolio` are silently "recycled" to become vectors of the appropriate length.

---

*Aside.* This question is arguably better suited to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than StackOverflow. And while it is reproducible, the example data is far too large to display and inspect in a post here, so I've switched to `n=10`, `yrs=5`.

Comment: Frank, thanks for taking the time to respond. Reduce seems like the ideal function for the purpose posed in my question (it even has an init argument) and it appears to be 10x faster than my loops. As other commenters have noted, on the other hand, Reduce's function is somewhat opaque and doesn't help my goal of clarity. People who read my paper won't be R experts.

Comment: _Aside._ It seems I am not the only one confused by the difference between StackOverflow and Code Review. I rejected the latter because that site asks,"_Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?_" This code is an example I created to ask how, in general, one should build an array requiring recursion. Any additional guidance on this topic also appreciated.

Comment: @DirkCotton If speed is a big concern you can do even better by using C++ in R with the Rcpp package. That may also improve readability of the code (since C is pretty easy to read, I think) by others. If speed isn't so important, I think your loop, using `pmax` instead of `max` (and so dropping the loop over `i`), shouldn't perform too badly. Dunno what field you're in that you expect people to be reading your code. [...onto your next comment...]

Comment: @DirkCotton The example certainly could have been simpler and smaller in size, if illustration was the aim. Yeah, the line between codereview.SE and SO is not so clear to me either (and I've never used the former). I tend to direct people there for questions like "how can I make this functioning code better?" ... though some times I try to answer such questions anyways, as in this instance :) Anyway, sorry I can't provide better guidance on that.

Comment: This will be published in a finance journal and I want to offer readers the code and data. I thought about C++, but now I'm thinking I will use my loop for the paper (for readability) and your suggestion for my own models. It's a lot faster, and concise. I think I get how Reduce works and I appreciate you suggesting it. Thanks, again.